Ошибка в Raize Components - "Error creating platform SDK. Active developer path is invalid"
Установил KonopkaControls-280-7.0For11.3 через GetIt Package Manager. 
При попытке запустить пример из папки Demo (как написано в файле !!Readme.txt:

To compile and run the RCDemo program in Delphi, simply load the RCDemo.dpr project file into Delphi and compile and run the program.

Чтобы скомпилировать и запустить программу RCDemo в Delphi, просто загрузите файл проекта RCDemo.dpr файл проекта в Delphi, скомпилируйте и запустите программу), выдаётся ошибка:

[Error] Error creating platform SDK. Active developer path is invalid.

В чём может быть причина? Путь установки?
